# How to use audio remote control device as input device for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have a bicycle app for which I would like to add user input capability in a safe way. I want to use a simple handlebar mounted, thumb activated audio remote control device (+vol, -vol, next track, previous track) for app input rather than user touching phone screen. I want to use the audio control buttons for app specific inputs - not related to audio.
I started out assuming I would need to bring in media player features to my main view controller.
I'm not getting any errors, but not getting any results

```
interface:
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter 

implementation:
inside view did load
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter =[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter] ;
[commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
        [self.mysong play]; //for testing
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess ;
    }];
```

Please help. Any suggestions on how to accept input from audio remote?
Is there something better than media plyer? A bluetooth method?

Comment: This looks fine. I would start by checking that the code you expect to run actually runs. There are many reasons `[self.mysong play]` might not play; you don't demonstrate that this is known good. And there are lots of other little things that could be wrong and you don't show. Start by setting breakpoints and make sure that the code you mean to run actually does or doesn't run. Start with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/becoming_a_now_playable_app, make sure that works, and then adapt to do what you want.

Comment: Thank-You Rob
As you observed the code was fine. Dumb mistake on my part.
This is an older project that I was updating. I had forgotten that I have a 'sound-off' button in the UI. After allowing sound all works fine.
I have a new twist - The remote control device is active while on 'other' screens in my app, not just the VC attached to the 'view did load' in which I added code. I did not expect that. What is the proper way to limit to just the desired VC? I can just add some booleans to 'view did appear/disappear' - is there a more proper way?  Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a new question. I recommend closing this one as "not reproducible" and opening a new one with the details of your issue. MPRemoteCommandCenter is not attached to view controllers in anyway. It's behavior isn't going to change unless you do write code to interact with it.